# How can I capture the request headers for a failed request during the load test

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

During load test few request are failing randomly, we want to capture the request headers and body of the failed requests.

We have enabled the extended log and selected options parameter substitution and data returned by server, and send messages only on error the headers are not getting captured.

In VuGen, we could see that request header.txt and request body.txt were getting created when we ran with same setting but in controller, only the response body and specific setup information file with the file details is getting created but not the request header.txt and request body.txt files.

Setup information file content is mentioned below. But not able to find these files.

```
Total=1
FileName1=t24.json
RequestHeaderFile=t28_RequestHeader.txt
ResponseHeaderFile=t28_ResponseHeader.txt
RawStepEndTime=1598996048524
RequestBodyFile=t28_RequestBody.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the Advanced trace option (in the RTS) to see request headers and body (if available).... Then "log on error" will include this info.